# How to upgrade php cURL to version 7.36.0?

Tags: php, linux, curl, centos

I have php curl 7.19.7 on my CentOS server, but I need to upgrade to 7.36.0.

I tried:

```
yum update php-curl
```

But I got:

```
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirror.t-home.mk
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

Comment: You can get the latest version directly from the [cURL website](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#LinuxRedhat).

Comment: Well my question is how, not from where.

Comment: [Installing an RPM on CentOS](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-rpm-using.html#s2-rpm-installing)

Comment: Have answered the question below

Comment: tnx, its suposed this question was answered already, I found the answer:
http://serverfault.com/questions/485227/upgrade-curl-to-latest-on-centos-6-3

Answer (score 20):

Use the city-fan repo ( part of the curl mirror http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#LinuxRedhat)

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel6.noarch.rpm
yum install libcurl
```

You can check for the latest version [here](http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/repoview/city-fan.org-release.html).

This currently updates curl from 7.19 to 7.40

Comment: FYI - this won't update the version of cURL PHP already uses.

Comment: @Meezaan-ud-Din Maybe usefull for others, you have to restart php (apache etc.) for php to use the updated curl

Comment: city-fan repo gives the latest versions, but unfortunately they're not always compiled with the newest curl options enabled `$ rpm -q curl` `curl-7.52.1-1.0.cf.rhel7.x86_64` `$ curl -I --dns-interface ppp2 stackoverflow.com` `curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.`

Comment: `The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: skipping http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-1-13.rhel6.noarch.rpm - transfer failed` now what? :)

Comment: Updated answer to a newer package, give it a try and let me know how it goes

Answer (score 8):

You can try this, it worked for me on RHEL7

1. create a new file /etc/yum.repos.d/city-fan.repo
2. paste in it:

   ```
       [CityFan]
       name=City Fan Repo
       baseurl=http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel$releasever/$basearch/
       enabled=1
       gpgcheck=0
   ```
3. run

   ```
       yum clean all
       yum install curl
   ```

Comment: What I read on the digital-ocean thread  
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-upgrade-curl-in-centos6
is that you want to set enabled=0 in the city-fan.repo file so that it does not become the default source of future upgrades.  You can instead manually enable the site using this call:
yum --enablerepo=city-fan.org update curl
   [ credit: jamieburchell ]

Comment: If one wants to temporarily enable the above `city-fan.repo` with `enabled=0`, then the command should be `yum --enablerepo=CityFan update curl`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following commands:

```
curl-config --version
sudo rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/city-fan.org-release-1-13.rhel6.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install libcurl
```