# BUG in curl 7.79.0 How to upgrade to 7.79.1 as PHP extension on Centos 7 + WHM/cPanel?

Tags: php, curl, cpanel, centos7

On our server we using Centos 7 + WHM/cPanel. Everything is the latest from the repos.
99% of our clients runs Wordpress sites on this server. And every Woocommerce shops using the most known billing plugin on Hungary.

The last upgrade of this plugin cause "Unsupported response code in HTTP response" with curl.

Plugin developer says he cannot do anything and providers need to be upgraded php-curl to version 7.79.1!

The question is: How can I compile curl as PHP extension?

I mean if I download the latest version and compile it, it installs as cli and not making the curl.so file.

Comment: Even if this is not related to programming: what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495444/how-to-upgrade-php-curl-to-version-7-36-0 help?